Supposed to be a simple question about entropy
Let say there is an urn which contains balls of different color. It is a well known formula to calculate entropy of balls in the urn:
$H = - \sum P_i\cdot\log(P_i)$
where $P_i = \frac{M_i}{N}$, where $M_i$ is the number of balls of $i^{th}$ color and N is total number of balls in the urn.
Value of entropy is at maximum when there are same number of balls of each color and 0 if all balls are same color.
That's basic.
Now let say we add a few more urns. How to calculate entropy now?
Intuitively, entropy should be maximal if there are same number of balls of each color in each urn.
Entropy should be 0 if all urns have same number of balls of same color (and no other balls).
In between, there is some entropy if all urns have same number of balls but each urn has balls of its own color; or if urns have not even number of balls or if some urns are empty etc.
We can calculate entropy separately for each urn using the formula above; we can calculate entropy between urns using similar formula; we can try to combine these entropies using arithmetic, but I feel there must be an elegant clean formula which I struggle to figure out.

Is each urn equally probable?

"Entropy" of what, exactly??

So you have a two-step experiment, first drawing an urn at random, then drawing a ball from that urn. That defines a mixture distribution, so use the result at Information entropy of a mixture distribution
If you have $n$ urns with urn entropies $H_1, H_2, \dotsc, H_n$ and draw urns from a distribution $p=(p_1, p_2, \dotsc, p_n)$ then the total entropy becomes
$$ H(p) + \sum_1^n p_i H_i $$

Let's consider an example when first urn has 10 blue balls, second urn has 10 green balls and third urn is empty. Applying your formula will give 0 entropy, because each urn's entropy is 0. However, entropy of this configuration should not be zero because it could be even more 'random' configuration when all three urns are filled with equal number of balls of all colors.

No, it will not give zero, you forgot the first term $H(p)$, the entropy of the mixture distribution
